# How can i deploy vue cli dist folder in direct admin control panel?

Tags: vue.js, deployment, vue-cli-3

I am creating a SPA (single page application) with `vue-cli`.

I run `npm run build` script then upload dist files in the public_html folder but didn't work

My hosting service uses [direct admin](https://www.directadmin.com/) as a web control panel.

I read the deployment [guide](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#general-guidelines)  but didn't help me

hosting service that I use works with Linux, PHP, and Apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Vue CLI assumes your app will be deployed at the root of a domain, e.g. https://www.my-app.com/. If your app is deployed at a sub-path, you will need to specify that sub-path using this option. For example, if your app is deployed at https://www.foobar.com/my-app/, set publicPath to '/my-app/'.

Read [public_path guide](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl)